# Is vegetable shortening a fully hydrogenated product or is it partially hydrogenated?

Tags: home-experiment, food-chemistry

Have the oils used to make vegetable shortening been fully hydrogenated or have they been only partially hydrogenated?

Comment: What's the label say?

Comment: As @ Todd Minehardt states, it depends... coconut oil, for example, is naturally 86% saturated.